# html5 video ширина ролика

Tags: html, css, html5, видео

каким образом можно растянуть html5 видео? оно сохраняет пропорции. видел вариант с

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
-moz-transform: scaleX(2);
```

но при ресайзе окна проблема проявляется вновь. можно, конечно, через ширину окна браузера, но я не знаю как работают эти множители в CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как вы добавляете видео простои пример:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N7nM0S_IJ6g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Ширина

```
width="560"
```

Высота

```
height="315"
```

если вы добавляете в html 5 то вот отдельный пример

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Соотвецтвенно нужно добавить код с видео в конкретный класс которому тоже можете дать и ширину и высоту

P.S. советую пробежатся [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так попробовать

```css
.wrapper-video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: auto;
}
.wrapper-video video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-video">
  <video controls="controls">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"/>
  </video>
</div>
```